# excel macros with empty dropdown

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, autofilter, vba

I'm working with AutoFilters in VBA with Microsoft Excel. I'm having an issue with how it handles arrays for filtering

i have created macro and auto filter is below.

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="Not Met"
```

but some times in rows i wont get calls with "Not Met" Condition and the drop down is empty at that time my macro gives error and doesn't progress ,how to over come this, is there any whay i can declare if no match found copy only header.

Comment: What's your full code?

Comment: i think i got the solution  'ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AC$500").AutoFilter Field:=14, Criteria1:="Not Met", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="*"'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have filtered your results you can use `SpecialCells` to test if you have found any results

```
Sub Test()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:AC500")
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="Not Met"
        If .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count > .Columns.Count Then
            'results found
        Else
            'results not found
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could adopt the following pattern:

```
With Worksheets("MySheetName") '<--| change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name and avoid referring to ActiveSheet which can be deceiving
    With .Range("AC", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) '<--| reference its columns A:AC cells from row 1 down to column A last not empty one
        .AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:="Not Met"
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then '<--| if any filered cells other than headers
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference filtered cells skipping headers
                ' your code to handle filtered data
            End With
        Else
            ' your code to handle no data match condition
        End If
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False '<-- remove autofilter
End With
```